# Pass an object as data of Autocomplete in React-js

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I am using the autocomplete of React-md. Actually I want to pass an array of objects in the Autocomplete and I have tried the following code.

```
<Autocomplete
    id="Autocomplete"
    placeholder="I want ..."
    className="md-cell md-cell--4"
    data={services_data[name]}
    filter={Autocomplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
    inputStyle={style.inputstyle}
    style={style.rootstyle}
    listStyle={style.liststyle}
    onAutocomplete={this.handleChange.bind(this.value)}
/>
```

I have the service_data of the format:

```
0: {fee: 100, name:"abc"}
1: {fee: 240, name="xyz"}
.
.
.
.
```

Now I want to pass an array of this object in Autocomplete data and want the suggestions to be listed down by the name. I have already shown what I have tried and I am getting an error for the same as soon as I type something in the field.
What I want is that After a user selects a value the complete objects of that name should be passed in the function handleChange.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `service_data` seems to be an object. Autocomplete expects an array, with a key `dataLabel`.

```
let transformedData = Object.values(service_data).map((item)=>{
  item.dataLabel = item.name; return item;
})
```

onAutoComplete is called with the suggestion, suggestionIndex, dataLabel of the item the user clicks. Your `handleChange` can access the complete object as shown below.

```
handleChange(suggestion, index, dataLabel){
  let completeObject  = service_data.find((item)=>(item.name==dataLabel))
  ...
}
```

Also your handleChange should be bound to `this` not `this.value`

```
<Autocomplete
  data={transformedData}
  onAutoComplete={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: is your service_data an object as I had assumed or is it an array?